# "Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception: Incorrect authentication data" happening in production, but NOT in localhost, using the same transport config

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I am using Zend_Mail to deliver a Zend Frameowrk based MVC application. The transport configuration is as follows:

```
; Mail (SMTP Transport)
resources.mail.transport.type       = smtp
resources.mail.transport.host       = "mail.mydomain.com"
resources.mail.transport.auth       = login
resources.mail.transport.username   = "no-reply@mydomain.com"
resources.mail.transport.password   = "mypasswordhere"
resources.mail.transport.register   = true

resources.mail.defaultFrom.email    = "no-reply@mydomain.com"
resources.mail.defaultFrom.name     = "Automatic email from mydomain.com"
resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.email = "no-reply@mydomain.com"
resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.name  = "Automatic email from mydomain.com"
```

The Zend application workflow set this as the default mail transport. This is working fine in localhost, but is failing in production. The send process is as follows:

```
$objMail = new Zend_Mail();

if( $fromEmail != null ){
    $objMail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
}

$objMail->addTo($to);
if( $cc != null ){
    $objMail->addCc($cc);
}
if( $bcc != null ){
    $objMail->addBcc($bcc);
}

$objMail->setSubject($subject);

if( $messageHtml != null ){
    $objMail->setBodyHtml($messageHtml, mb_detect_encoding($messageHtml));
}
if( $messageTxt != null ){
    $objMail->setBodyText($messageTxt, mb_detect_encoding($messageTxt));
}
$objMail->send();
```

The exception in production is:

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Incorrect authentication data&#13;
' in /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:431
Stack trace:
<<issue 0>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp/Auth/Login.php(95): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(235)
<<issue 1>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(217): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login->auth()
<<issue 2>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
<<issue 3>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
<<issue 4>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
<<issue 5>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/application/controllers/MailController.php(404): Zend_Mail->send()
<<issue 6>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): MailController->sendmailAction()
<<issue 7>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('sendmailActi...')
<<issue 8>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
<<issue 9>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
<<issue 10>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
<<issue 11>> /home/myuser/public_html/subdomains/myapp/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
<<issue 12>> {main}
```

As I said, I can send emails from localhost with no problem using the same transport configuration, and even I have a Gmail account checking new emails with the same configuration (at least the same authentication credentials) and It is working.

I've tested creating a different email account to use as my SMTP transport. Instead of "no-reply@mydomain.com", I called it "noreply@mydomain.com", with a totally differenmt password. Again, it works fine from localhost, but fails in production.

**But I've tested it with an already existing account (the "admin@mydomain.com" account credentials) and it works in both, production and localhost!!**

Why can this happen?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the ZF code, the message `Incorrect authentication data` is being returned by the mail server itself rather than anything specific to Zend Framework.  The message itself is probably coming back in the form of a `535` error code.

If there is any way possible, see if you can get a packet capture from the production system using `tcpdump`, Wireshark or your preferred network analyzer.

Since you said it works fine with a different account on both production and development, I don't think auth is failing because you aren't using SSL/TLS, or that `mail.mydomain.com` resolves to a different IP address on the two systems.

At this point I'd be interested to see the packet capture of the mail transaction as that may be the only way to see a discrepancy between the login process on the 2 systems.

Hope that helps.